# Center my header link without stretching the page

Tags: html, css

I cannot seem to be able to center my link h1 without it stretching the page. I know how to center it using text-align: center, and it centers, the link is stretching the full width of the page.

Can I center the link without it stretching?

```css
.navigation {
 padding-top: 70px;
 padding-bottom: 70px;
 position: relative;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 
}

.brand-text {
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
 font-size: 50px;
 color: black;
 -webkit-transition: color 1000ms ease;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}


.brand-text:hover {
 color: grey;
 
}

.nav-brand {
 text-decoration:none;
}

.nav-menu {
 text-align: center;
}

.nav-link {
 padding-top: 7px;
 padding-bottom: 7px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: grey;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 -webkit-transition: color 700ms ease;
 position: relative;
}

.nav-link:hover {
 color: black;
}

.current {
  color: black;
}

.current:hover {
  color:
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Josh Corbett</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
 <div class="navigation">
  <a class="nav-brand" href="#"><h1 class="brand-text">Title</h1></a>
  <div class="container">
   <nav class="nav-menu" role="navigation">
    <a class="nav-link current" href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you mean by stretching? What is the page supposed to look like? How do you see that what you have is undesirable?

Comment: Reverse the order, put the link into the h1.

Answer (score 0):

You can add overflow: hidden; in your brand text. 
You can also try doing

```
#LinkText {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      overflow: hidden;
}
```

and give id of LinkText to H1 tag.

Answer (score 0):

The anchor is stretching the full width of the page because the h1 tag is a block element and takes up entire width of page...hence the anchor will adjust it's size to the size of the header tag..sticking to placing the anchor tag as parent....here is a solution

add the css codes below

```
  #title {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%);
  border: medium solid !important;
}
```

**Note:transform property is not supported by old broswers....**

See snippet below

```js
position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%);
  border: medium solid !important;
}
```

```css
.navigation {
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.brand-text {
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: black;
  -webkit-transition: color 1000ms ease;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}
.brand-text:hover {
  color: grey;
}
.nav-brand {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-menu {
  text-align: center;
}
.nav-link {
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: color 700ms ease;
  position: relative;
}
.nav-link:hover {
  color: black;
}
.current {
  color: black;
}
.current:hover {
  color:
}
#title {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%);
  border: medium solid !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Josh Corbett</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="navigation">
    <a class="nav-brand" href="#" id='title'><h1 class="brand-text">Title</h1></a>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="nav-menu" role="navigation">
        <a class="nav-link current" href="#">Portfolio</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```